# Multiple POM Issues in spring mvc

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

template used while project creation 
http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/help/org.springframework.templates.mvc-3.2.2.zip

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.winhill</groupId>
    <artifactId>elabsexpert</artifactId>
    <name>elabsexpert</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Errors -

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer javax.inject:javax.inject:pom:1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.inject:javax.inject:pom:1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org  pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer javax.servlet:jstl:pom:1.2 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.servlet:jstl:pom:1.2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer javax.servlet:servlet-api:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.servlet:servlet-api:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org    pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:pom:2.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:pom:2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org    pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for junit:junit:jar:4.7: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer junit:junit:pom:4.7 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact junit:junit:pom:4.7 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org  pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact log4j:log4j:pom:1.2.15 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.aspectj:aspectjrt:pom:1.6.10 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.aspectj:aspectjrt:pom:1.6.10 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org   pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:pom:1.6.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:pom:1.6.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.6.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:pom:1.6.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org    pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:pom:1.6.6 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:pom:1.6.6 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org    pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-context:pom:3.1.1.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-context:pom:3.1.1.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org   pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.springframework:spring-webmvc:pom:3.1.1.RELEASE from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:pom:3.1.1.RELEASE from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org  pom.xml /elabsexpert    line 1  Maven Dependency Problem
```

Please help, I am new to spring and facing this problem at start itself :'(

Environment details -

Windows - 8.1
Eclipse Luna
maven - 3.2.2

Comment: Try to build it from command line using `mvn`, not in Eclipse. Also make sure that your internet connection is working. You may also try to clean (delete) your local Maven cache (`~/.m2/repository/`).

Comment: First make sure that you are able to access 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2'. Then remove all .lastupdated files from .m2/repository. Once maven tries to connect to internet and couldn't find artifacts, it caches the information in repository and doesn't connect to internet until the update interval of central repository has elapsed. As @Jakub Jirutka suggested you can rename repository and try again.

Comment: @Bala, if you try to access the specified path, its not accessible. it gives 404 error

Comment: @Jakub Jirutka : Thanks !

could you please help me to understand why it works from command line and not from eclipse. and what could be done to make it work from eclipse too ?

Comment: @Anand Chavan, url has got an extra symbol at the end. Remove that symbol and try. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. If you don't have configured maven's settings.xml them maven downloads artifacts from central repository. It doesn't look like eclipse issue. I am using Luna with maven but facing no issues. Are you behind proxy? In such a case you need to configure proxy in eclipse.